# Windows 2008 - Define IP Order by port or service

Tags: windows-server-2008, smtp

I have a Windows 2008 server that has three IP bound to the NIC. I can select which IP Windows SMTP listens to, but I want to also set the IP address used when mail is sent. Where would I set which outbound IP to use when sending email?

Without using real IPs, here is an example what I have setup. Three IPs associated with the server:
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3

I setup the binding on 10.0.0.2 for port 25 in the SMTP server settings, so that it is the only IP that will respond for inbound. When I look at the email header from an email sent from that server, it lists the server with an address of 10.0.0.3. I would like it to use 10.0.0.2 so that when reverse DNS is performed, it maps back correctly.

Comment: Maybe I need to look at Windows routing tables: http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2005/02/25/380481.aspx  -  Myth #4

Comment: Hey! Nice username you've got there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A specific smtp server instance only binds to one address.  If you want to separate them then you need to fire up a second server, but it'll have to bind to a different port (which shouldn't be that big of a problem for outgoing traffic).

Comment: I tried creating a separate instance, I used a different IP for it to listen and I assigned a different port to the original instance. But the new one used the same IP for sending emails as the first instance.

Comment: Which version of Exchange are you using?

Comment: I'm not, this I'm using the SMTP Server that comes with Windows Server